# Items per page not taking an effect [Extjs]

Tags: javascript, extjs, pagination, extjs4

I have wrote the extjs code for the pagination. It showed me all the data into grid but I set the itemsPerPage = 2. Here I used extjs with Grid + Panel. I think it is some minor mistake but I am new to extjs and all, so I cannot figured it out. I have tried but no luck so far.

```
Ext.onReady(function () {
var itemsPerPage = 2;   // set the number of items you want per page

var store   =   Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    storeId: 'employeeStore',
    autoLoad: false,
    pageSize: itemsPerPage, 
    fields: ['firstname', 'lastname', 'seniority', 'dep', 'hired'],
    data: [{
        firstname: "Michael",
        lastname: "Scott"
    }, {
        firstname: "Dwight",
        lastname: "Schrute"
    }, {
        firstname: "Jim",
        lastname: "Halpert"
    }, {
        firstname: "Kevin",
        lastname: "Malone"
    }, {
        firstname: "Angela",
        lastname: "Martin"
    }],
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'example.json',  // url that will load data with respect to start and limit params
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'blah',
            totalProperty: 'total'
        }
    }
});

// specify segment of data you want to load using params
store.load({
    params:{
        start:0,    
        limit: itemsPerPage
    }
});

Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    title: 'Pagination',        
    store: store,       
    columns: [{
        text: 'First Name',
        dataIndex: 'firstname',
        field: 'textfield',
        flex : 1,   
    }, {
        text: 'Last Name',
        dataIndex: 'lastname',
        flex : 1,   
            field:{
                xtype:'textfield',
                allowBlank:false
            }           
    }],
    id : 'SimpleGrid',
    width: 500,
    dockedItems: [{
        xtype: 'pagingtoolbar',
        store: store,   // same store GridPanel is using
        dock: 'bottom',
        displayInfo: true
    }],
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

});

To use paging, pass the paging requirements to the server when the store is first loaded.

```
store.load({
params: {
    // specify params for the first page load if using paging
    start: 0,          
    limit: myPageSize,
    // other params
    foo:   'bar'
}
```

});

Here I used extjs + Grid + Panel.

Kind Regards,

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the comment to url field:

```
proxy: {
    ...
    url: 'example.json',  // url that will load data with respect to start and limit params
    ...
}
```

extjs sends request to the server when it loads with all needed params. For example: example.json?start=0&limit=2&page=1
So you should limit it on the server and then send back to extjs

Here you can look at the working example, where limits was handled manually.

http://jsfiddle.net/jardalu/TE4ah/

Comment: I had checked with the all required documents but none suggest your way, so I wonder. When we load the store at that time it has the params which you suggested so no need to pass with the file. Am I right?

Comment: I have edited my question for server side paramas please look.